# Selected popup menu item background color set

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, popup

I just one to ask that is there anybody who can chanse background color of the selected menuitem? I was searching a lot in this topic and I didnt find any working solution yet :(

So I have a recyclerview with a 3dot imageview and when i click on this image a popup menu is show. In my list i have items and all item have a status and I use this popup menu to show status options, but the items already have default status and i would like that when popup menu appear, that defoult item of the manu has a different background, than the others.

I found one solution, that is with radiobuttons, so when menu item is selected, i set the item checket, so with the radiobutton is workign well, but that's not that I really want :/

I tried with styles, like following:

@style/PopupMenu

@color/black
        @drawable/selector_popup_menu_background
        @drawable/selector_popup_menu_dropdown
        @drawable/selector_menu_item
        @color/light_blue

(sorry i paste it here the code, but after i publish the question it didnt show it well)

and in the drawable files i tried the following:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/light_blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/light_blue" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
```

But for me it seems like state checked not working at all with the background, only with the radio buttons :(

I also tried inside my popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener the following:

val view = popup.menu.findItem(item.itemId).actionView as TextView
view.background = context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_spinner_item_background_shape)

but nothing happend...

I can aso change the selecting highlight color when item is clicked, but this background color disappear after dismiss the menu.

Does anyone has a working solution for this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Style Named PopUp

```
 <selector>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <item android:drawable="@color/light_blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/light_blue" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
  </selector>
```

apply `android:background="@drawable/popup"`

```
 <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbID"
            android:text="check"
            android:background="@drawable/popup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            />
```

output ss

Unchecked

[image: uncheck]

Checked

[image: checked]

chenge  `@style/PopupMenu` to  `android:background="@drawable/popup"`

hope helpful for you