# setOnCheckedChangeListener for every radiobutton

Tags: android, radio-button, oncheckedchanged

I have a radiogroup containing several radiobuttons whose background color is grey. When I click on a radiobutton I would need the clicked one to change background color to black, while others would keep the grey background. I know I can set OnCheckedChangeListeners for all radiobuttons like this:

if(checked) then setBackGroundColor to black;

else setBackGroundColor to grey;

but is there any more efficient way to do that? Like write just one OnCheckedChangeListener for the whole group

Comment: I thought there was one listener for the whole group.

Comment: you also try like this in your design https://stackoverflow.com/a/67724183/8133524 
or  `id.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));`

Answer (score 0):

Create a selector -> drawable/radio_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/black" /> <!-- checked -->
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:color="@color/grey" /> <!-- unchecked -->
</selector>
```

And in the RadioButton view add

```
android:buttonTint="@drawable/radio_selector"
```

This works on api 21+
If you are using a lower minimum api you will need to set buttonTint in a style

```
   <style name="radio_style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
       <item name="buttonTint">@drawable/radio_selector</item>
   </style>
```

and add this instead to your RadionButton

```
style="@style/radio_style"
```